# Gitlab-runner in docker with ci/cd dind error

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I have gitlab-runner running inside the docker on my server. This gitlab-runner is successfully registered for my gitlab.
But when I run ci/cd I get an error:

```
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://docker:2375. Is the docker daemon running?
```

[error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v88wH.png)

[my ci file task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6Gbr.png)

[my config.toml file for gitlab-runner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amwyF.png)

Please tell me how to fix this error.

I've already recreated gitlab-runner and redid the ci file several times. Nothing worked. I created gitlab-runner with the command -

```
docker run -d --name gitlab-runner --restart always -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```

Then going into the docker itself I ran the command -

```
gitlab-runner register --url https://gitlab.com --token <my_token>
```

In CI/CD Pipeline log

```
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:17
Using Docker executor with image docker:git ...
Starting service docker:dind ...
Pulling docker image docker:dind ...
Using docker image sha256:881c987bf80d40ddcc0f01d845242611380eba9115d9eeab12713c5215c21959 for docker:dind with digest docker@sha256:5edfe3067bdd8b76818b036d8ef61846696af4d458ba527356c5484fcd692c2a ...
Waiting for services to be up and running (timeout 30 seconds)...
Pulling docker image docker:git ...
Using docker image sha256:fce9ca002cbb40452df4ab64ec9b726fd1ba7fbc2eb3b4b482da87f6013541b5 for docker:git with digest docker@sha256:e86452c5f015fafa3957fa4cf7a38ac4b091a317fc0481f00f36dae6d8b065af ...
Preparing environment
00:02
Running on <runner_info> via 428a77e8bbfe...
Getting source from Git repository
00:06
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/<road>/.git/
Checking out a64f955b as detached HEAD (ref is develop)...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:04
Using docker image sha256:fce9ca002cbb40452df4ab64ec9b726fd1ba7fbc2eb3b4b482da87f6013541b5 for docker:git with digest docker@sha256:e86452c5f015fafa3957fa4cf7a38ac4b091a317fc0481f00f36dae6d8b065af ...
$ echo "running publish state"
running publish state
$ docker build -t $TAG_LATEST .
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://docker:2375. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please don't include pictures of text. Instead, write the text/code/output directly in your question. It would also be useful to have the **full** job output from top to bottom.

Comment: @sytech, update logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `docker run` to start your runner, you also need to pass the `--privileged` flag.

```bash
docker run --privileged ...
```

You may also need to set the variables `DOCKER_HOST` and `DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR` in your job.

```yaml
myjob:
  # ...
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
```

Comment: How do I know what value to put in DOCKER_HOST and DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR?

Comment: @VadimPopov you put the values exactly as I described here. When you specify `- docker:dind` in your `services:` it has the hostname of `docker`. If you're using some other registry or image, you should specify `alias: docker` for the dind service. That's the value for `DOCKER_HOST` -- the dind service container. Setting `DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR` to an empty value forces TLS to be disabled and port 2375 to be used by the dind daemon.

Comment: Isn't running containers in privileged mode not recommended by GitLab? As per the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/security/#usage-of-docker-executor)